# Handling dependency of functions in python

Tags: python, automation

I want to write a script for automation of sequence of events, where the execution of the next sequence depends upon the success of the previous step. There are basically 8 functions which I want to call onne by one and if one fails, I want to exit at that point. So how can i handle this in python?

Comment: Python is already imperative. What's the problem? Do you want some fancy chaining?

Comment: Here at SO, we suggest, improve and help you along the way. We don't write code for you.

Comment: `if-else` statement can do what you want

Comment: In perl I used to create assertions and then if one failed, script used to exit giving [ERROR] as the result and if it passed the result of that particular assertion was marked as [PASS]. But that using the automation framework. In  this case, I am not using any framework. So just wanted to know whats the best possible way of doing this  in python?

Comment: I know things like this can be easily done using if-else :) but any chaining that can used ?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions)?

Comment: @Jonathan: if there is something from your experience that you could share for handling situations like this gracefully in python, you are welcome. Also, its pretty apparent from the question that I am not expecting any code

Comment: @rohitvyawahare No problem, i have added some code for your benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Basic `if`, and `elif` statements can overcome your needs.

Say you had a function that returned a variable.

```
def f(z):
    data = z
    return data
```

You can analyse the result with a if. Assign a new variable to the function `f`:

```
x = f(0)
if x == 0:
    #do something
```

So if x is equal to 0, continue with code. But what is c = 1?

```
import os
x = f(1)
if c != 0:
    os._exit(0)
```

`os._exit(0)` quits the program.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend taking a look at [pytest](http://pytest.org/) (or one of the other Python testing frameworks).

This guide should get you up and running quickly:

http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html